# Android display half TextView and half ImageView if true else display only TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, show-hide

I'm trying to display a text inside a TextView in the left side of the screen and an image inside ImageView in the right side when "true":

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/displayMessageCenter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/displayMessageTop"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textMessageText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dividerId" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/messagePicture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dividerId"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="right"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/dividerId"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_above="@id/leftTextGenericDialog"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftTextGenericDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#FF72CCCC"
        android:text="SEND RESPONSE"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sendicon"
        android:layout_above="@+id/closeButton"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/closeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_close_animation"
        android:onClick="closeActivity"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and if "false" to hide the image and display just the TextView with the text in the center. The hiding will be something like:

```
if(true) imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

but I don't know how to align the ImageView and the TextView to be easier to hide/show just the ImageView when needed.

I'm new in Android development so please be gentle :)

Comment: `android:layout_weigh` is for LinearLayout only ... put invisible view in center of the parent with size 1x1 then put `textMessageText` to left of this(and align parent left)  and `messagePicture` on the right of this((and align parent left)) both with with 0dp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Relative layout on these cases, you can use alignParentLeft=true for the TextView and alignParentRight=true for the ImageView, but if you wanted the TextView to adjust whenever the ImageView is visible or not. Use something like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="text"
      android:layout_weight="0.5"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      />

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="0.5"
      android:visibility="gone"

      />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For ***true*** condition, you can just set

```
android:alignParentLeft="true"
```

and

```
android:alignParentRight="true"
```

to your TextView and ImageView corresponsdingly.

For ***false*** condition, you can programmatically set rules to your TextView. Just get the TextView using *findViewById* and set rules like following:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textMessageText);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
tv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```